# System Tray Won't Close Popout Plasma 5.18

Tags: focus, kde-plasma, system-tray

I have installed KDE Plasma 5.18 on Zorin 16.3 Pro (an Ubuntu 20 based distro).  Whenever I click on the system tray (bluetooth, stacer, wifi) the popout is available, but clicking an option in the popout or clicking the desktop does not close the popout.  This popout will even stay open after opening the settings, or application in which it is relevant.  I have to click on the particular icon that I originally accessed to close the popout.

It's strange to see such behavior as most desktop environments do not have this functionality.  Any thoughts or questions are welcome.

After a web search, with only icons not showing being the closest to my issue, I have looked into libappindicator, but do not know what, if any, applications depend on this library.  I do not want to remove it arbitrarily as I don't want to break something else in the process.

```
~$ dpkg -L libappindicator
dpkg-query: package 'libappindicator' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
~$ apt list --installed | grep libappindicator

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libappindicator3-1/focal,now 12.10.1+20.04.20200408.1-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]


~$ dpkg -L libappindicator3-1
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappindicator3.so.1.0.0
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libappindicator3-1
/usr/share/doc/libappindicator3-1/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libappindicator3-1/copyright
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappindicator3.so.1
```

This is confusing as dpkg doesn't see it, though apt shows it (with 3-1) and dpkg gives no hint to what libappindicator3-1 is used for/with.